# Нужно ли удалять указатель на nullptr?

Tags: c++

Нужно ли в c++ прописывать delete для указатель на nullpt?

Comment: Вопрос - зачем? Если вы имеете в виду проверку - то не нужно, `delete` и так понимает. Если *явно* писать `delete nullptr;` или `int * a = nullptr; delete a;` - то *зачем*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем понятно, что имелось ввиду. Функция `delete` удаляет не указатель, а обьект по этому указателю. Соответственно, `nullptr` указывает в никуда, потому удалять по нему нечего. Ответ - нет.

Comment: из iso - Значение первого аргумента, переданного функции освобождения, может быть значением нулевого указателя; если так, и если функция освобождения предоставлена ​​в стандартной библиотеке, вызов не имеет никакого эффекта.